# How does one open a popup window INSIDE an iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe, popup, frames, window.open

Simply put, how can I open a popup window INSIDE an iframe?  Whether I use window.open in the parent window or the iframe, the popup window loads on top of the parent.  Is it possible to open up a new window such that it's confined to the iframe?

Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to open a new window so that it is confined to the `iframe`. Functionality similar to what you're asking for could be achieved using a [JavaScript lightbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightbox_%28JavaScript%29).

Comment: Thank you very much for your constructive answer.  I will look into the JavaScript lightbox method, as a result.  Take care.